# Mac updated to OSX 10.8 is causing Windows network account lockout

Tags: networking, osx-mountain-lion

I updated my Mac to OSX 10.8 and now every time I try to login to my work network (a windows network) it locks my account. Each time, my sysadmin unlocks my account and I am able to successfully login one time but then, if I login again (after restart or sleep) I am locked out. Is anyone experiencing this? Anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I suspect cached credentials somewhere. If you have an automatic connection set up, and your password has changed, this is usually the cause. Have a look at any Windows shares you are mounting automatically (e.g. "Connect As").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also recommend deleting any network passwords saved in Keychain on the Mac client.This is mostly the case with Mac users who connect to Windows file shares via Finder and save password in Keychain the first time and forget about it. The Keychain passwords may be old and each time this device resumes from hibernation the login attempt to the Windows shares fail without any user notification on the OSX devices.